# Logout on recycle

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis-7

On a production environment I have an IIS hosted asp.net application, actually many web applications. Every app consumes a lot of memory but at the moment the only way to limit it is recycle (nHibernate seems to be leaking memory, and it's creating large amount of string collections). The problem is that after the recycle it keeps loging users out or rather dropping the session ? On local computer I couldn't recreate the issue. I've tryed using state server with no luck, the issue contined, would SQL State saving chane anything or am I just miss leaded or missing something ?

Comment: We have just this issue on a large application. Recycling a worker process does result in attached sessions losing their authentication, and we're using the state server and loadbalanced sticky sessions. We were assured that it was down to using IE6 with 32-bit IIS6, and changing either would improve matters. It's disappointing to see you're using IIS7 with the same problem, and I am coming to the conclusion that a SQLServer session database may be the only way to solve it. However: are you using 32-bit or 64-bit servers?

Comment: Very interesting Andrew ! I am running it on 64 bits and at some point I experimented with suggestion from one of Microsoft MVPs to force worker proces to run on 32, but results alhough at first were promising at the end were catastrophicall. Process crashed randomly lossing all the data and mixed up our database (actually ORM fault caused by crash)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer was surprising and it was related to view state errors that I logged in my application, I found a proper explanation on one of the [MSDN sites](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/555353), this line in particular :

> **regarding machineKey**
>
> "[...] When the application pool is running **under a user account**, the above keys are not generated leading to an intermittent invalid viewstate error."

In conclusion all that had to be done was [generating a machine key](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772287%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) and recycle is not causing users to re-authenticate anymore.

Answer (score 3):

When the application pool is recycled all sessions are lost if the session data is stored on memory (InProc, default).

Sessions are created by placing a cookie with a key in the user's browser and keeping that key on the server state machine.

If you use a SQL Server to store your sessions, you'll avoid the server loosing the session information. [Session-State modes on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You wrote you tried StateServer mode, but stateserver mode works like sqlserver If I don't know it wrong. StateServer can be started from windows services and within your web.config you can set your servers ip address (which state server is started and working).

If stateserver doesn't work for you somehow, I doubt sql server will. Problem might be in another area I feel.

> ASP.NET session state supports several different storage options for
>   session data. Each option is identified by a value in the
>   SessionStateMode enumeration. The following list describes the
>   available session state modes:
>
> InProc mode, which stores session state in memory on the Web server.
>   This is the default.
>
> **StateServer mode**, which stores session state in a separate process
>   called the ASP.NET state service. This ensures that **session state is
>   preserved if the Web application is restarted** and also makes session
>   state available to multiple Web servers in a Web farm.
>
> **SQLServer** mode stores session state in a SQL Server database. This
>   ensures that **session state is preserved if the Web application is
>   restarted** and also makes session state available to multiple Web
>   servers in a Web farm.
>
> Custom mode, which enables you to specify a custom storage provider.
>
> Off mode, which disables session state.
>
> You can specify which mode you want ASP.NET session state to use by
>   assigning a SessionStateMode enumeration values to the mode attribute
>   of the sessionState element in your application's Web.config file.
>   Modes other than InProc and Off require additional parameters, such as
>   connection-string values as discussed later in this topic. You can
>   view the currently selected session state by accessing the value of
>   the HttpSessionState.Mode property.