# how to troubleshoot random logouts in asp.net application using forms authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a reasonably large scale web application talking to multiple applications running on the intranet. The default session timeout is 20 min. This application has certain editable widgets. Certain users of this application have experienced random logouts while they were editing data on the widgets after only logging in few min. I have not seen such logout on my machine. How shall one can go for troubleshooting such logouts?

Application logs quite often has following kind of entries

Event code: 4005 
Event message: Forms authentication failed for the request. Reason: The ticket supplied has expired. 
Event time: 19/09/2013 16:19:00 
Event time (UTC): 19/09/2013 15:19:00 
Event ID: bfedac01cc514bedb236347b8585a4e3 
Event sequence: 31083 
Event occurrence: 820 
Event detail code: 50202

Application information: 
    Application domain: /xx/xxxxxxx   Trust level: Full 
    Application Virtual Path: / 
    Application Path: C:\xxx\xxx\ 
    Machine name: xxxxx

Process information: 
    Process ID: 56940 
    Process name: w3wp.exe 
    Account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE

Request information: 
    Request URL: http://www.xxxx   Request path: /xxxxx.aspx 
    User host address: xxx.xxx.xxx.205 
    User:
    Is authenticated: False 
    Authentication Type:
    Thread account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE

Name to authenticate:

Comment: My guess is your app pool is recycling. See the answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10268248/logout-on-recycle

Comment: Yep, I have actually addressed this in the answer to the question you asked a hour before this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18876103/handling-sessionstate-in-asp-net

Comment: Forms authentication cookies survive pool recycling easily as it is persisted in cookies! In fact, this would be really troublesome for everyone if this wouldn't work!

Comment: @dev: is the sliding expiration enabled?

Comment: @Thabo Is it possible to get history of recycle log in IIS 6.0

Comment: @Wiktor yes the sliding expiration is true.

Answer (score 3):

The only reliable way to troubleshoot such unexpected logouts is to ask users to **log** their sessions using a client-side http debugger, like Fiddler.

Running your application with fiddler open in the background at the client-side will log all requests and responses. Then, when an unexpected failure occurs, the user selects the complete trace (all requests), exports everything to a file and sends to you.

Then you, as a developer, open up Fiddler, import user trace and analyze it around the failed request.

What you search for is the behavior of responses with respect to cookies. Normally, the forms authentication cookie is sent to the server with the request so that user is authenticated. On the other hand, failed request should probably have **no such cookie** which would suggest that is has been somehow removed.

And this is where it becomes interesting. The only way to remove the cookie is to either remove it manually or to receive a prior response from the server that deletes the cookie. From your, developer, perspective, deleting the cookie is triggered when you call `FormsAuthentication.SignOut`.

When analyzing the trace you just try to find the **culprit request** - a request **prior** to the request that failed - the one that caused the cookie to be deleted at the client-side.

What is so specific in such culprit request - it depends on your server side code and there are dozens of possible causes, starting from configuration issues to buggy code.

However, this is definitely a way to start your investigation.

Comment: I have just discovered the worker process is recycling often after reaching a memory limit of 1GB on IIS 6. We are using in proc session and wondering if switching to out of process options would help

Comment: Sessions **should not** affect your clients that use Forms Authentication - authentication is carried in cookies and it doesn't matter that the worker process restarts between requests. If you implemented forms authentication correctly then this **should not** be an issue. However, if you have a custom code that somehow uses Session, then you are in trouble.

Comment: Just checked application logs and quite often i have informational message like above in the question

Comment: Forms authentication ticket expired. I guess you should just set the timeout to a larger value in forms section of the authentication section in web.config.